# Deconstruct Expression<Func<...>> and collection into an .Intersect()

Tags: c#, linq

I have an abstraction of my MongoDB querying whereby I pass it an expression tree to filter documents retrieved from the database. eg:

```
var filterExpression = x => x.IsPublished && x.Topics.Contains("fish");
MyCollection.Get(filterExpression);
```

In the implementation of this, I then do:

```
_collection.Find(filterExpression).ToListAsync();
```

I also have a fake for this, for testing:

```
Collection.Where(expression.Compile());
```

Now I have requirement to do an Intersect query eg get me all documents that are published, and have topics about 'fish' or 'chips'.

In mongo, I have to use:

```
Builders<TDAO>.Filter.AnyIn(setInDocument, setToIntersect)
```

where the parameters have types:

```
Expression<Func<TDAO, IEnumerable<string>>> setInDocument
IEnumerable<string> setToIntersect
```

Is there a way to get from those types to an Intersect eg something like:

`.Where(setInDocument.Intersect(setToIntersect).Any())`

Comment: I assume that `setInDocument` is `IEnumerable<string>`, not `IEnumerable<string>>>`?

Comment: oops; yes, it is

Comment: sorry, ```setInDocument``` is an expression tree to a field within the document

Comment: your question is unclear. Why do you want to use `Expression<Func<TDAO, IEnumerable<string>>>` and `IEnumerable<string>` in the fake implementation? Shouldn't you use the expression tree instead?

Comment: i've updated my question @Albert

Comment: `Where` takes a lambda with a parameter - `Any` doesn't meet that requirement - can you update the `Where` to use a parameter?